# How to calculate equilibrium time for a communicating vessel with height difference?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, flow, equilibrium, bernoulli-equation

The scenario is that a communicating vessel or a U tube without lids is filled with water. There is a height difference between the two pipes of this tube. Then there will be hydraulic pressure and finally, the height of the liquid will flatten out. I'd like to know how long it will take to achieve equilibrium.

Comment: You could use bernoulli's equation to find the instantaneous velocity difference between the heights and integrate to get the total time to cover height difference.

Comment: cool, many many thanks!!!